# Three.JS Object Material CleanUp

Tags: javascript, three.js

Newbie trying to understand what's a standard practice for you experts.  I'm loading a GLTF model with multiple objects that change per the user's input.  (Change being different material like color or shininess/metalness setting, etc.)  I have a color picker that the user chooses from that currently creates a new material each time the user makes a selection of a different swatch from the color picker.

In terms of standard practice - should I just be creating the meshbasicmaterial once, and then changing it (i.e. setting a new color, changing the value of shininess etc.?)  Should I be creating the meshbasicmaterial every time I want to change the color, etc.?  If I'm creating a new meshbasicmaterial every time, should I be disposing of the previous one prior to creating the new?  Or, maybe you do something completely different?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I just be creating the meshbasicmaterial once, and then changing it (i.e. setting a new color, changing the value of shininess etc.?)

Yes. There is no need to create materials over and over again just because a property value changes.

If you don't need a material instance anymore (for whatever reasons), always call `dispose()` on the object to potentially free internal resources like the respective shader program.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the info.  Follow-up question - how do you typically track all of the items you need to free?  Do you simply traverse the items?  Create an object list?

Comment: That depends on your application and when objects become obsolete. You can call `dispose()` methods at any time so it's really up to you to decide when the time is right to get rid of stuff.